# How do you programmatically enable the "Develop" menu in Safari 15 on macOS 12 (Monterey)?

Tags: safari, preferences, defaults

In previous versions of macOS, it was possible to enable the "Develop" menu using the following command:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDevelopMenu -bool true
```

Unfortunately, this command no longer works as of Safari 15 on macOS 12 (Monterey).

Answer (score 0):

**Safari** has to have been opened at least one time, then with **Safari** closed, then in **Terminal** run the following two *commands*:

```zsh
defaults write com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker ShowDevelopMenu -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDevelopMenu -bool true
```

Then open **Safari** and the **Develop** *menu* will appear.

---

**Notes:**

The **shell** *commands*, shown above, were tested in **Terminal** under **macOS Monterey** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>
- <sup>1</sup> In this particular case one must give **Full Disk Access** to **Terminal** for the second `defaults` *command* listed to work properly. 
   
   In this particular case it's the `defaults write

The correct *keys* were ascertained using a clean install of **macOS Monterey** and a `diff` done between the output of `defaults read` on both of the target *domains* before and after manually changing **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **Show Develop menu in menu bar** and after deleting the entries and verifying the **Develop** *menu* did to exist, it took both *keys* for it to show again programmatically.

Comment: I followed these instructions exactly and it did not enable the develop menu for me.

Comment: What's interesting is that after running these commands, the option `Show develop menu in menu bar` is checked in Safari preferences, but the menu is not displayed. Perhaps there's another key that needs to be set?

Comment: @johndbritton, I do not post answers that I have not previous tested and this does work under the conditions stated. However, maybe you didn't understand what "Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed."... Which means... In this particular case one must give **Full Disk Access** to **Terminal** for the `defaults` _command_ to work properly. Sorry, I forgot to add it explicitly. (Added to answer now.)

Comment: @johndbritton, Also, based on the time of your first comment and the time of downvote I'm assuming it was you that downvote my answer. I'd appreciate you removing your down-vote considering this does actually work, thanks.

Comment: Terminal has Full Disk Access but this answer does not work. As I noted above, the `Show develop menu in menu bar` option is checked, but it is not shown.

Answer (score -2):

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDevelopMenu -bool true;
```

This line is working for me, can't help. Did you restart the browser to reflect changes?